# Divisor sum of totient function squared

Tags: number-theory, totient-function, divisor-sum

I was wondering if it's possible to express the following sum as a function of $n$:
$$
\sum_{d|n} [\phi(d)]^2
$$

similarly to the known relation:
$$
\sum_{d|n} \phi(d) = n
$$
where $\phi$ is the totient function.

Comment: Have you tried writing it out for the first few $n$?

Comment: The relevant OEIS sequence is [A029939](https://oeis.org/A029939).  You can read more about the sequence there.